# Can't find Spark libraries when using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I used to code Scala within the terminal, but now I'm trying 
with the ScalaIDE for Eclipse.
However, I've got one big problem:

> error: not found: value sc

I've tried to add those libraries

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

But then it displays:

> object apache is not a member of package org

So I don't know what to do....

In my IntelliJ project my `build.sbt` is pretty empty:

```
name := "test"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

Comment: I don't use SBT so can't comment about how to fix it with SBT, but it's not an Eclipse bug - you just haven't got the right libraries associated with the Eclipse project. I can use Scala and Spark just fine with Eclipse. There's a tutorial for using SBT/Eclipse/Spark here http://www.nodalpoint.com/development-and-deployment-of-spark-applications-with-scala-eclipse-and-sbt-part-1-installation-configuration/ (I've not used it)

Comment: Can you edit your question with your build.sbt contents ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it a sbt project? make sure you have eclipse plugin for scala/sbt, and import it as a sbt project.

also, add the dependency on the `build.sbt`

nevertheless, I prefer [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) :)